# Tenant with name projects/**/tenants/** not found using Google Cloud talent solution API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

Description:

**Code**:

String projectId = "*****";

String tenantId = "***-ay7tp";

```
        try (JobServiceClient jobServiceClient = JobServiceClient.create()) {

        // Construct the list jobs request
        ListJobsRequest.Builder requestBuilder = ListJobsRequest.newBuilder()
                .setParent("projects/" + projectId + "/tenants/" + tenantId).setFilter("status = \"OPEN\"")
                .setJobView(JobView.JOB_VIEW_FULL); // specify which fields to include in the response

        

        // Use the JobServiceClient to list the jobs
        ListJobsPagedResponse response1 = jobServiceClient.listJobs(requestBuilder.build());
        System.out.println(response1.toString());

        TenantName parent = TenantName.of(projectId, tenantId);
        ListJobsRequest request = ListJobsRequest.newBuilder().setParent(parent.toString())
                .setFilter("status = \"OPEN\"").build();

        // Print the details of the first 10 jobs in the response
        int count = 0;
        for (com.google.cloud.talent.v4.Job job : jobServiceClient.listJobs(request).iterateAll()) {
            System.out.println("Job title: " + job.getTitle());
            System.out.println("Job description: " + job.getDescription());
            System.out.println("Job posting date: " + job.getPostingPublishTime().toString());
            System.out.println("Job company name: " + job.getCompanyDisplayName());
            System.out.println("Job ID: " + job.getName().substring(job.getName().lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            count++;
            if (count >= 10) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

**error**:

NOT_FOUND: Tenant with name projects/**/tenants/** not found.
Request ID for tracking: *******-*****-48e8-961e-*************:*****************==

Comment: com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Tenant projects/**/tenants/** is not allowed to access company with id projects/shareproone/tenants/**/companies/**. Request ID for tracking: **==]